# Issue with using C# code with accessing Google Drive/Files using Service Account

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, maui

I am developing an App using Visual Studio/Net MAUI for Windows/Android/IOS, which needs to automatically access mp3 files on Google Drive and play them directly.

Having looked online, I discovered that if I use OAuth2, the App user has to do authentication with a Google sign in prompt. I am instead using a Service Account.

I am getting errors with the code that I have added to achieve the above.

I have added the following code based on my understanding of how I can do the Google Drive authentication and retrieving the file directory/name from Google Drive:

In MauiProgram.c I have added the configuration for the Json file containing the Service Account details:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using var FStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.apps.json");
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonStream(FStream)
             .Build();
```

The following code is in a separate ViewModel is for the file access:

```
    public async void PlayMP3Files()
    {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(FStream);
        BaseClientService Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "My App"
        });

        var folderName = "My Folder";
        var request = Service.Files.List();

        request.Q = $"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='{folderName}'";
        var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
        string folder = result.Files.FirstOrDefault();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            var fileName = "My File";
            request = Service.Files.List();
            request.Q = $"mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='{fileName}'";
            result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
            string file = result.Files.FirstOrDefault();
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Play file
            }
        }
    }
```

When building the above, it fails with following errors:

1. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

   Error    CS0103  The name 'FStream' does not exist in the current context
2. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

   Error    CS1061  'BaseClientService' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no accessible extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'BaseClientService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am not sure how to link the FStream to its usage in Mauiprogram.c.

I think I have included the directive/assembly reference for BaseClientService. Looking ate the code behind of Google.Apis.Services, there does not appear to be a declaration for Files.

Any help in resolving the above issues would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to include `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State` - any C# developer knows what those are.  Just the error code and message is usually sufficient

Comment: Why are you declaring the variable `Service` (which would more conventionally be `service`) as type `BaseClientService` then trying to use members that are specific to `DriveService`? Just declare it as type `DriveService` - or just use `var` as you have elsewhere.

Comment: You declare the variable `FStream` as a local variable, but you expect it to be available in another class. That can't work. You should pass the `FStream` down to your ViewModel or use an IoC container to resolve this dependency in your ViewModel.